# How to change macro recording into VBA for loop for larger range?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok So I'm trying to make this easier to follow so I get better help.
This is the code I currently have from a recorded macro.
This is one iteration and I need 153. What it does: 1. Clears B2 and sets format as general since it automatically changes to number after each iteration. 2. Sheet NB Load Book Cell R[4]C[-1] is referenced and pasted into sheet Max Amps cell B2. 3. Calculate Sheet button is pressed. 4. The values in sheet Max Amps cells B6 and B7 are copied and pasted as a number into sheet NB Load Book cells B5 and C5.

The next iteration for example would use sheet NB Load Book cell R[5]C[-1] and enter into same place and copy same cells and paste as number into Sheet NB Load Book cells B6 and C6.
 Need this all the way until Row 153 ...so until R[152]C[-1].

```
Sub Macro10()
    Sheets("Max Amps").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='NB Load Book'!R[4]C[-1]"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("NB Load Book").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Max Amps").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("NB Load Book").Select
    Range("C5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Once again I know this is messy but I'm a beginner. How can I make this code apply to 153 iterations without typing them all out? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description above your code is inconsistent with your recorded Macro, where as the code shown copies & pastes different from/to different cells than you describe as intended.

In any case, the below should do it:

```
Sub Macro10()

myRCval = 4
myBval = 5
myCval = 5 

For i = 1 To 153


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps").Range("B1").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps").Range("B1").NumberFormat = "General"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps").Range("B1").Value = "='NB Load Book'!R[" & myRCval & "]C[-1]"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps").Calculate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps").Range("B6").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NB Load Book").Range("B" & myBval).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Max Amps").Range("B7").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NB Load Book").Range("C" & myCval).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

myRCval = myRCval + 1
myBval = myBval + 1
myCval = myCval + 1
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

You may modify the variables as you see fit.

Comment: I tried using this, except it keeps storing it in the same cell. It stores it all in Sheet NB Load Book B5 and C5. That cell keeps changing with each iteration but I need the values to be stored in the the next row and so on. Like b6 c6 and b7 c7 etc

Comment: @samred The code that I've posted copies the data from Max Amps B6 & B7 then pastes these values into NB Load Book B5 & C5. In the next iteration it will copy from Max Amps B6 & B7 then pastes into NB .. B6 & C6, and so on.  The copied from values in Max Amps are constant but the NB Load Book values are variable.

Comment: @samred does the copied values in Max Amps need to be variable and increase the copied from row in each iteration?

Comment: Also should myval in the bottom be myRCval?

Comment: The copied values in Max Amps changes based on the initial NB Load Book value that is pasted into cell B1. The copied values from Max Amps b6 and b7 are always number/dates respectively, but the actual number or date changes based on what is entered into Max Amps B1.

Comment: @samred Oh yes, `myval` should be `myRCval`. I've corrected and updated the code.

Comment: @samred Can you try again with the updated code and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Not sure what changed but now it's not calculating. It just populates those fields with "#Value" and the message box pops up. Could you make the first code available?  I'm also making it i = 1 to 3 instead of i = 1 to 153 since each iteration takes about 1 minute

I undo-ed until I got the old code that worked. I changed the variables to myRCval. But now it's still only populating NB Load Book B5 and C5

Comment: Your current code doesn't work the way it is right now because you still have myval instead of myRCval in your 8th line of code. Regardless, still populating only b5 and c5

Comment: @samred updated the code again. Can you please try now?

Comment: working, thanks! Last question, how do you learn to do this? I've seen tutorialspoint for definitions and stuff but not actually how to put together code like this.

Comment: @samred you learn by working on solving different problems. Each time you learn something new. I'm sure you learned from this, so next time you need to use a loop, you can probably re-issue this with some level of understanding. Glad the code worked for you. You may please mark my answer as accepted using the green check mark sign.